# Is there proxy configuration of Java client for big query?

Tags: java, google-bigquery

When I try the codes in [Authenticating Google API with a service account with Java API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11827817/authenticating-google-api-with-a-service-account-with-java-api), I get a failure and need go through a proxy. I found there is the [same question for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906757/where-is-proxy-configuration-to-allow-bq-tool-to-connect-to-the-internetnt). Is there any solution for Java client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, we do support HTTP proxies.

There are two choices of HTTP transport classes: `NetHttpTransport` or `ApacheHttpTransport` (based on 4.0)

This doc shows how to use `NetHttpTransport`:
https://developers.google.com/bigquery/articles/gettingstartedwithjava

You can then set system properties here to configure the proxy:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html#Proxies